# Spark Java : Is optimal threshold used for calculating ROC in Spark BinaryClassificationMetrics class

Tags: apache-spark, classification, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I am using Spark `mlib's` `BinaryClassificationMetrics` class to generate the metrics for the output of `RandomForestClassificationModel`. I have gone through the Spark docs and I am able to generate `thresholds`, `precisionByThreshold`, `recallByThreshold`, `roc` and `pr`.

I wanted to know if any particular threshold value is used while generating `roc`. This is because in  [ROC wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) it says that:

> The ROC curve is created by plotting the true positive rate (TPR) against the false positive rate (FPR) at various threshold settings.

I was wondering if any optimal threshold value is used or not while generating ROC in Spark. If not why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's 0.5, BinaryClassificationMetrics uses BinaryLabelCounter whose label counting method looks like so:

```
def +=(label: Double): BinaryLabelCounter = {
  // Though we assume 1.0 for positive and 0.0 for negative, the following check will handle
  // -1.0 for negative as well.
  if (label > 0.5) numPositives += 1L else numNegatives += 1L
  this
}
```